# Montouch tablview as subview issue

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am new to Xamarin IOS and I have a problem with creating nested layouts in IOS as like in Android(some text controls and a list view) . I added a tableview but not sure how to add some text and image controls in a view and add the tableview below the text and image controls. Also I am using ViewPager in Android and is there an equivalent control that I can use in IOS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use `UIScrollView` and enable paggin there. The only issue that you need always to set the `ContentSize` for it, to make it scroll properly. So you should set the common Size of inner content.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [monotouch.dialog](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/monotouch.dialog/) for rapid tableview development. Once you get the hang of it, it makes creating tables a lot easier.